# Is there a way to hide (and then show again) track changes in Word before a desired date?

Tags: vba, date, ms-word

I often have to check Word documents with multiple rounds of editing. To make things easier, I would like to be able to run a macro that prompts me to input a date and then any tracking before this date would be hidden, leaving only track changes made on or after the inputted date. Ideally, hitting the macro again would toggle the hidden track changes back to being shown.

I don't have an in-progress code as such, but do have two separate macros, each doing related things. The first is a simple toggle to hide and show insertions and deletions:

```
Sub ShowHideMarkup()
ActiveWindow.View.ShowInsertionsAndDeletions = Not _
ActiveWindow.View.ShowInsertionsAndDeletions
ActiveWindow.View.ShowFormatChanges = Not _
ActiveWindow.View.ShowFormatChanges
End Sub
```

And the second is one I've seen posted a few times online (created by Graham Mayor) - this one prompts for a date and then accepts earlier revisions:

```
Sub AcceptTrackingBeforeGivenDate()
Dim oRev As Revision
Dim oKeepDate As Date
Dim strRsp As String
While Not IsDate(strRsp)
strRsp = InputBox("Enter earliest date to keep", _
"Accept Changes Before Date", _
"1 Jan 2021")
If Len(strRsp) = 0 Then Exit Sub
Wend
oKeepDate = CDate(strRsp)
For Each oRev In ActiveDocument.Revisions
If oRev.Date < oKeepDate Then
oRev.Accept
End If
Next oRev
End Sub
```

I'm really not sure how to combine the two. Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Many thanks in advance!

Luke

Comment: Thank you macropod and apologies - I have edited the comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two macros cannot be combined to do as you want. The:

- first simply toggles the track-changes view on/off for *all* tracked changes.
- second simply accepts all changes before a specified date, meaning they no longer exist in the document and, unless all the 'accepts' are undone or discarded (by not saving the document), provides no means of 'unhiding' those changes.

Word has no capacity to display some tracked changes and hide others based on the date.

The kludgy workaround I had in mind is equivalent to what the second macro does - without saving the modified document.

Do note that, even without using Track Changes, Word allows you to use its document comparison feature to compare two versions of the same document (e.g. the current version and a version in your backups). You could do the same thing by saving daily/weekly versions of the documents (different filenames, of course), to compare any two versions against each other.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation macropod!

Comment: See added last para in my answer.